# Check for a list the elements of which all contain only whitespaces in HTML

Tags: python, flask

I'm building an app in Flask. I'm extracting a variable `items` (which is a list) and displaying each of its elements in a separate cell.

```
<tr>
   <th>Some heading</th>
   {% for item in items %}
      <td>{{ item }}</td>
   {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

However, some `items` lists only contain elements consisting of whitespaces only, for example:

`items = ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ']`

I want to check that this is NOT the case and create a table row only if at least one element of `items` contains more than whitespaces. `{% if items %}` doesn't help because the list has elements. Is there any other way? I don't know JavaScript, but I would be glad to look into that too if there is a way.

Comment: Why can't you just trim each elements in array and then check like `% if item.strip() %`

Comment: @ShashankGb thanks, I ended up doing something similar (concatenated the elements and checked if the string contains whitespace only).

Answer (score 0):

With python you can check it with:

```
if all(map(lambds s: s.strip(),items)):
```

With JS

```
if (items.every((item) => item.trim()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, found a way out through introducing an `items_check` in the app file. Basically, I joined the elements into a string and checked it for containing only whitespace. Now `{% if items_check %}` works :)

Answer (score 0):

@armgar
You need to modify the code and place if condition outside the row of table so that row will only get created when the item in the list is not a whitespace.
I tried this and it's working for me.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Some heading</th>
   </tr>
   {% for item in items %}
       {% if item %}
           <tr>
               <td>{{item | trim }}</td>
           </tr>
       {% endif %}

   {% endfor %}
</table>
```